# c# web browser control default printer page orientation

Tags: c#, forms, printing, webbrowser-control, landscape

I am printing HTML pages from my Windows Form program, using Webbrowser compenent. Web browser compenent is using Internet Explorer settings.

I must print without show user to PageSetup Dialog (directly printing from codebehind side). Some pages are landspace, some pages are portrait. I tried Css media print options but IE is not accepting them. PageSetupDialog is not allowing landspace setting without .show method and I didn't connect PageSetupDialog to Webbrowser compenent (webbrowser do not allow them)

How can I print landspace pages via Webbrowser compenent without showing PageSetupDialog ? Code Example ?

Comment: anyone have an idea or not ? please help me